# Converter o formato da data que o usuário digita

Tags: php, postgresql

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte código para formatar a data que o usuário informa e insere no meu banco:

```
$arrayData['data_validade'] = date_format("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$this->$arrayData)));
```

Só que, essa date_format, funciona só para a data atual, mas eu nao quero a data atual, quero a data que o usuário informa através do meu datapicker.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dessa maneira que eu consegui resolver:

```
$arrayData['data_validade'] = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $arrayData['data_validade'])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a melhor maneira de se revolver situações do tipo, seja com o objeto `Datetime`. É sempre bom procurar utilizar os novos recursos do PHP.

```
$data = '17/07/2014';
$data_en = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
print_r($data_en->format('Y-m-d')); //2014-07-17
```

Answer (score 0):

Se está usando o postgres, pode formatar a data a qualquer hora até em um insert, diferente do mysql.

Antes da consulta principal essa linha isso vai converter todos os campos datas de `YYYY-MM-DD` para `DD/MM/YYYY` de uma vez só.

```
SET DATESTYLE TO SQL, DMY;
INSERT INTO tabela(data) VALUES('31/12/2015');
```