# Como tratar dados de uma pesquisa do tipo Date na cláusula where no Postgres?

Tags: php, sql, ajax, postgresql

Eu tenho uma tela onde possui uma lista de títulos de pagamentos de uma empresa, e preciso fazer uma busca dinâmica a partir da data de emissão do título. A ideia, é que, quando o usuário digitar a data em um campo de pesquisa, esses dados serão passados dinamicamente via `AJAX` para um arquivo onde lá estará a consulta `SQL`.
A minha dúvida, é como eu irei montar a minha cláusula `WHERE`?.
Ex: `WHERE data_emissao ILIKE '%2015-01-01%'`
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Vai usar like em uma coluna date? explica melhor isso, between não seria mais adequado?

Comment: Quando o usuário digitar a data, ex: 23/10/2015, todos os títulos lançados nesse dia serão retornados em uma lista. Basicamente é isso, eu pensei em usar o between mais essa função trabalha com duas datas uma inicial e a outra final, e no caso aqui eu só tenho uma data. Eai?

Comment: E tem algum problema com ? `WHERE data_emissao = '2015-01-01'`, se quiser pode passar a data como `dd/mm/yyyy` direto no banco, veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85863/91)

Comment: Sim, por que além da pesquisa pela data tem a razão social, cnpj e número do título, ambos são tratados com string e a data de emissão é do tipo date. Com isso retorna o seguinte erro: `ERRO: sintaxe de entrada é inválida para tipo date: "2015"
SQL state: 22007`

Comment: A duvida que eu tenho é que tipo você definiu a coluna pra estar querendo usar `ILIKE`.  Ela esta varchar ou Timestamp?

Comment: O usuário informa uma data completa ou só um pedaço, mês, ano etc? Coloca o código que vc tem até agora, pode dar um clareada.

Comment: Segue o código: `SELECT     titulo.id_titulo,       titulo.numero_empresa,  participante.razao_social,  
           participante.cpf_cnpj,  titulo.data_emissao,    titulo.valor,
           titulo.autorizado
FROM       titulo
INNER JOIN participante ON( titulo.id_participante = participante.id_participante )
WHERE      titulo.numero_empresa     ILIKE '%2015%'
OR         participante.razao_social ILIKE '%2015%'
OR         participante.cpf_cnpj     ILIKE '%2015%'
ORDER BY   id_titulo DESC
LIMIT      10 OFFSET 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Pode comparar um pedaço da data com a função [extract](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT), o primeiro argumento é tipo desejado e o segundo o nome do campo.

```
SELECT ... WHERE data_emissao = '2015-10-23'

SELECT ... WHERE extract(year from data_emissao) = 2015
```

Comment: `date_part('year', data_emissao)`, creio ser mais simples, ele é um alias.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, não sou fã do `extract()` se não me engano ele é padrão ansi, então vc consegue portar um consulta fácil com ele do que com `date_part`, teste ai no mysql, `select extract(year from now())`

Comment: ah compreendo, você quer disser que é melhor usar `extract`, pois caso ele altere o bando era funcionar normalmente.

Comment: @rray, de certa forma funciona, porém, quando os dados vem nos formatos '2015-01' ou uma string a consulta falha.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert exato, haha e com certeza o `extract()` é meio verboso mesmo, mas tem um motivo :)

Comment: @BrunoDuarte, tem mais algum formato que o usuário pode informar? além dos dois que vc passou?

Comment: Não é só esses dois formatos mesmo.