# Como configurar o Postgres para aceitar data em formato PT-BR?

Tags: postgresql, data, formatação

#### Situação

Digamos que eu tenha um *form* na qual o usuário preencha um campo *date*, DD-MM-YYYY.

#### Pergunta

Como posso fazer o *postgres* aceitar este formato normalmente?

- Sem necessidade de fazer `to_timestamp('14/06/2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

#### Adendo

- O *SELECT* ser `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- O *INSERT* aceitar `YYYY-MM-DD` ou `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Comment: Sim é possível, :D até tinha uma resposta .... só não estou achando

Comment: @rray hehe, foi uma intencional pra ajuda, pois vi que no site não tinha. :D

Comment: Eu usava isso, só que sempre definia essa configuração na sessão.

Comment: @rray `SET datestyle TO "ISO, DMY";`?

Comment: Isso, mesmo, hehe nem sempre vc mode mexer de forma globa no servidor aí ja viu. [Achei](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85863/91) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisando um pouco encontrei [esta resposta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126911).

O passos são simples :

1. Verificar seu atual datestyle "ISO, DMY" ou "IOS, MDY".
2. Agora Dependendo do que você quer no postgres **MDY** ou **DMY**

   ALTER DATABASE "my_database_name" SET datestyle TO "ISO, DMY";

   ou

   ALTER DATABASE "my_database_name" SET datestyle TO "ISO, MDY";
3. Apos isto sera necessário reiniciar o servidor

   sudo service postgresql restart

   Ou

   sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
4. Teste a configuração

   Query: SELECT '20/12/2016'::date Output: "2016-12-20"

   Or

   Query: SELECT '12/19/2016'::date Output: "2016-12-19"

Neste caso usamos, `ALTER DATABASE "my_database_name" SET datestyle TO "ISO, DMY";`.

Comment: Faço uma ressalva, certa vez foi necessário alterar isso também no arquivo de configuração do postgres